# Cannot Download a File from our Website in one of two implementations

Tags: browser, download

We have been working on this website for years and we have one problem that we can't figure out. We cannot download a file from it. Before we officially deploy wikitimelines.net, we have to have this functionality. We can demonstrate a section of code that downloads a file and the exact same code, just in a different place, that does not work. The code is in Visual Foxpro 9 and a middle tier system called Foxweb (foxweb.com). We understand this is an old MS RDBMS. We use it because it is so incredibly fast. But the code is not the problem, as we can demonstrate that it works.

Here is the code:

```
Response.Buffer = .T.
FileName = [articlesozoy0l71.wta]
ContentType = "application/unknown"
FileExtension = Upper(Justext(FileName))
ContentType = "application/unknown"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName)
FileContent = ReadFile(FileName)
* Specify size so that progress bar works properly
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Server.ToString(Len(FileContent)))
Response.ContentType = ContentType
* Send file to browser
Response.Write(FileContent)
Response.End
```

Now, if you point your (hopefully Chrome) browser to:

http://wikitimelines.net/download7.fwx

And sure enough, this works as expected, downloading the file "articlesozoy0l71.wta" from our server.

Now we have incorporated this EXACT section of code into our website at:

http://wikitimelines.net

This is our website where we are attempting to create timelines out of all of Wikipedia (where there are dates). Click on the plus sign next to any topic. This will reveal a listing of all the Wikipedia articles within that particular timeline. Along with every article there is a small image of a box with a small arrow pointing up and to the right. When clicked this runs the exact same code listed above and which works when you executed the standalone file. In this context, it does nothing. We don't see any errors in the Chrome "console" when clicked.

So our question is, why does this "file download script" work in one context but not in our website. Same code, same server and same middleware?

Is there a security issue we are missing here?

Comment: I guess that I am somewhat unclear.  You say:  "The code is in Visual Foxpro 9" but then go on to say "But the code is not the problem,"    So is the problem your Foxpro code or your web service (.NET - language unknown) code?

Comment: Well, no it isent the code. It seems to be a security issue.

I am running Windows 10 as my testing environment. I have IIS version 10.0.17134.1

Comment: I beleive my downloads are being blocked by IIS on a MIME type basis, but I dont know how to confirm that.


I am now reading the blog:


https://blogs.infosupport.com/getting-iis-to-serve-any-file-type/


But it seems overly complicated from this.

Comment: So I guess the question boils down to how do I get my server (IIS) to take what I am writing out to the browser and allow the user to save it on their computer, as a file (with a ".TLA" extension). I think it is that simple.